# React JS check whether strict mode is enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-strictmode

Is there any way to know whether the strict mode is enabled in React?

```
useEffect(() => {

  if(strictModeEnabled) {}

})
```

I didn't find any information in the docs.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I have a cleanup logic that should run only once. It doesn't work now with the change in v18 where effects running twice.

Comment: with refs you can understand is your running first or twice @undefined

Comment: No, because the clean-up always runs once. @HakobSargsyan

Comment: Check my answer @undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check if React's \`StrictMode\` is on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524752/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-reacts-strictmode-is-on)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
export const useEffectOnce = ( effect )=> {

  const destroyFunc = useRef();
  const effectCalled = useRef(false);
  const renderAfterCalled = useRef(false);
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  if (effectCalled.current) {
      renderAfterCalled.current = true;
  }

  useEffect( ()=> {

      // only execute the effect first time around
      if (!effectCalled.current) { 
        destroyFunc.current = effect();
        effectCalled.current = true;
      }

      // this forces one render after the effect is run
      setVal(val => val + 1);

      return ()=> {
        // if the comp didn't render since the useEffect was called,
        // we know it's the dummy React cycle
        if (!renderAfterCalled.current) { return; }
        if (destroyFunc.current) { destroyFunc.current(); }
      };
  }, []);
};
```

call it by

```
useEffectOnce( ()=> {
    console.log('my effect is running');
    return () => console.log('my effect is destroying');
});
```

Read more [here](https://dev.to/ag-grid/react-18-avoiding-use-effect-getting-called-twice-4i9e)

Comment: This isn't the ultimate solution as it causes a redundant render cycle. I prefer to check somehow whether strict mode is enabled

Comment: Your cleanup is only for development ? @undefined

Comment: No, for both production and dev

Comment: StrictMode is a developer tool, it runs only in development mode. It does not affect the production build in any way whatsoever.
In order to identify and detect any problems within the application and show warning messages, StrictMode renders every component inside the application twice.

@undefined , in the production everything will be good for you

Comment: I can't work in dev mode, I need it to run only once

Comment: Remove <React.StrictMode> from the index js and work @undefined , it will be same as you disable react strict mode by some condition

Comment: What you want to do in this if(strictModeEnabled) {} condition @undefined ?