# Is there a way to check if React's `StrictMode` is on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-strictmode

**Is there a way in React -- either in code or via the React devtools -- to see if a component is being rendered in [React's `StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)?** In my dream world, there would be some kind of constant I could `console.log`, say a bool of `React.isStrictModeOnForThisComponentRendering`; or maybe when you inspect a component in the React devtools, it would say somewhere in the side panel if it's rendering in StrictMode or not.

To be clear, this question is:

- **Not** about how do you enable StrictMode. (The answer is `<React.StrictMode>`, although it can also be set via configs in some frameworks, e.g., `Next.js`)
- Specifically discussing React's `StrictMode`, **not** [JavaScript's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (`'use strict';`) or [TypeScript's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) strict mode. It's an overloaded phrase, but watcha gonna do?
- Motivated by the confusion you get due to unexpected double rendering with React's StrictMode. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24502) or [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode/61897567) for a sense of the frustration it can cause. It would be nice to have an easy way to verify a component is running in StrictMode even if you can't tell where in the component tree StrictMode has been enabled.

Comment: I didn't think it could be *not* obvious when it's "on". The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) are pretty clear and explicit in a note right at the top of the page. If you are running a development build and are rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component, it's "on".

Comment: @DrewReese: yeah, you'd think so, but turns out I'm in a case where it's not obvious. I'm like 95% sure I'm seeing a double render `useEffect` problem due to StrictMode, but `React.StrictMode` is nowhere in my codebase, nor is it enabled via `Next.js` config. However, if I wrap the problematic component with `<React.StrictMode>`, the doubling issue does not double again into quadruple, so that _seems_ to indicate the component is already in StrictMode, but I can't find anywhere that would be causing it.

Comment: Same problem, did you manage to solve it @Erdős-Bacon?

Comment: @napolux: I wish. I've got an annoying approach. I'll write it up as a solution but I sure ain't accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: In case you're still looking for this, I'm using a hook that checks console overrides to detect strict mode: https://github.com/Oblosys/react-hook-tracer/blob/v1.2.0/packages/react-hook-tracer/src/hooks/hookUtil.ts#L16

Comment: @Erdős-Bacon I came here for exactly the same reason. I created a production version of the app for the same basic component and it was firing only 1 useEffect. So I know that even though I removed the <React.SctrictMode> provider the number of effects are two, now we can have two possiblities, it runs twice always in development or the React StrictMode is enforced somewhere else.  Having different behaviour depending on environment is baffling to me.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a clear or definitive way, but you can purposefully trigger a warning that is supposed to only occur in React's StrictMode. For example:

- You could purposefully create a dummy component that makes use of an unsafe lifecycle, and [it should trigger a warning](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#identifying-unsafe-lifecycles). This is a bit of a hassle since -- if you're using only functional components throughout your app -- you must create a class component to make use of the unsafe lifecycle methods.
- You could purposefully use a (deprecated) string ref in a component, and [it should trigger a warning](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#warning-about-legacy-string-ref-api-usage). This is easier but uglier than the above with functional components: you can put it in any component's JSX, but it will cause your app to just completely break if it's a functional component. But the warning should at least still appear before the app breaks. **CAVEAT:** I just tried reproducing this and while I'm still confident my app is in React StrictMode, I can no longer get the string ref to trigger the warning as I had been seeing it before, it's only breaking the app. Not sure what has changed or I'm doing differently, but this might not be as good a check as the above option.

In any case, this warning will contain some text like this

```
... found within a strict-mode tree ...
```

which seems like reasonably good proof that the component is rendering in StrictMode. Would be nice to have a more direct helper function, but it works in a pinch.